# Trouble using Math.max.apply over array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, max

I am trying to find the maximum number within each of four subarrays, push each max to a new array that includes all four maxes and return that array. When I run this code it returns an array with four values, but they are all null. What am I doing wrong?

```
largest = [];

function largestOfFour(arr) {
  for (i = 0; arr.length > i; i++) {
    var tempSub = arr.slice(i , i + 1);
    largest.push(Math.max.apply(Math, tempSub));
  } 
  return largest;
}

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]], "");
```

Comment: What is your expected output? `[ 5, 27, 39, 1001 ]`?

Comment: Why are you passing 2 parameters to `largestOfFour()`?

Comment: @Halcyon Yes, thats what I am looking for

Comment: @RocketHazmat The second parameter is for a test I believe on freecodecamp. I tried running without it but nothing changed.

Comment: That's because `largestOfFour(arr)` only lists one parameter in its signature.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: The extra value sent to the function is not matched to a parameter in the function, but sending extra values to a function doesn't keep the code from working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using `slice` to get part of the array, you are getting an array with the item inside it. The variable `tempSub` doesn't contain an array of values like `[4, 5, 1, 3]`, it contains an array of arrays of values, like `[[4, 5, 1, 3]]`. When you send that into the `max` method it will not be able to get the maximum value because you don't send the values into the method, you send a single value that is an array.

Use `arr[i]` to get an item in the array instead of `slice`.

Also, you should declare the variable `largest` inside the function, so that the function can be used more than once without retaining the result from previous calls. The variable `i` should also be local.

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  var largest = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    largest.push(Math.max.apply(Math, arr[i]));
  } 
  return largest;
}

var result = largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);

// show result in snippet
document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: I noticed that and tried something similar but I still had the tempSub code in there. That is exactly what I am trying to do and thanks for explaining it so clearly.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to run a function on each array that gets its largest value:

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
    return arr.map(function(v){
        return Math.max.apply(Math, v);
    });
}
```

Or using [ES6 arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (which not many browsers actually support):

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
    return arr.map(v => Math.max.apply(Math, v));
}
```

Comment: That is a very nice alternative way to accomplish what I am trying to do, thanks for sharing. Much more eloquent than my rudimentary code above.

Comment: Note that the `map` method is not supported in all browsers either. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: @Guffa: True, but I think you can safely assume no one's using IE < 9, no?  Also there's a polyfill if you *really* need to support IE 8.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: You can definitely not safely assume that. This for example says that about 11% is using it: https://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0 Other sources have other statistics for IE 8, but they are never zero.